# how to make a html button to execute a shell script?

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, shell

my problem is i try to make an button on a Website such as Submit to execute an bash script on server side
my first try was with Php an Exec but it dont work
html site:

```
<html>
<form action="exec.php"  method ="get">
    <input type="submit" value="BestÃ¤tigen">
</form>
</html>
```

php script:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/var/www/html/testsite/sc.sh");
header('Location: http://192.168.2.1/hs.html?success=true');
?>
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/testfile
```

the www-data user owns all of these files
if i click the button it only resend me to the http://192.168.2.1/hs.html?success=true
but doesnt execute the script
if i execute the php with ssh it works

please anyone check my code pls and help me if there is an better option to execute a shell script with websites it would make me happy to know them.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this function is not disabled in php.ini file. Take a look on this [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)

If it is not, then check the value returned by shell_exec(). According to [shell_exec() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), this function will return:

> A string containing the output from the executed command, false if the pipe
> cannot be established or null if an error occurs or the command produces no
> output.

Try code like this in the php script page. Please note that by doing this, Location header will fail.

```
<?php
$retVal=shell_exec("/var/www/html/testsite/sc.sh");
if (!$retVal) {
    echo "<p>Pipe was not established</p>";
} else
   echo "<p>Pipe was established:<br>";
   if (is_null($retVal)) {
       echo "No value returned or command nod executed";
   } else {
       echo "Value returned: $retVal";
   }
   echo "</p>";
}
# header('Location: http://192.168.2.1/hs.html?success=true');
?>
```

If `$retVal` is set to **false** then you'll see *Pipe was not established* message. Otherwise if it is not false but set to **null** means command was not executed or was executed and there was no output .
In this scenario, if you're expecting any output consider the following:

There are also some other things you'd like to try. Such as using touch complete path (*/usr/bin/touch*) instead of just using command name.

Regards

Comment: i checked this function and try your code but where do i read the echo output?

Comment: Hey @JustinRöhrig, As the php script output. I've added some more things to the answer. Pls take a look

Comment: thx for this but if i use that code i get: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /var/www/html/testsite/exec.php on line 8

Comment: Did you realize there's a missing ")" ? 
Let me add it

Comment: Thanks for this but i am New in PHP an didnt know how To read the Output of the Command can you Please Tell me

Comment: Check and try the code now. It's been corrected.

Comment: Yeah but where ist the Output if i execute It from the web

Comment: Most probably in the output page. (The browser). If anything is written there then location header() will fail (as per my experience, been a while with out playing with PHP anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini is different in shell. Use phpinfo() trough web to check some settings which prevents the execution. Use the php.ini used by www-data (you can get it from phpinfo) and execute the script with user www-data and with that ini in shell.

`php -c /path-to-custom/php.ini your-script.php`

OR: simply turn on php error logging and check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that this command does not return anything, you need to add something like that

```
<?php
if(shell_exec("/var/www/html/testsite/sc.sh | echo 1 2>&1")) {
   header('Location: http://192.168.2.1/hs.html?success=true');
}
?>
```